# An Array within an Array?

Tags: java, arrays

Ok so as I plod along in my classes in Java coding I was asked to use this code to count the instances of lowercase letters that were generated by a method for a character array. I can follow the code up to the point it throws out stuff like. "counts[chars[currentIndex] - 'a']++;"

So yes, the codes says it's making a public method called countLetters, it needs to be called somewhere in the main body and needs a character array parameter to fire up, got that. It creates a integer array called counts and it's size is 26, (same size as total # of lowercase letters in alphabet, got that.) It then fires up a for function, commonly needed for arrays. Creates a variable called currentIndex, default value 0, while current index is less than the size of chars character array do the stuff below. Then it gets to what the for loop actually is DOING. and uh, what the hell is it doing? it's increasing the size of count's index? The whole thing is weird, like some array within an array and subtracting the numeric value of lowercase 'a'? It's modifying the currentIndex of count somehow. Why is subtracting the numeric value of 'a' necessary? Wouldn't - 26 suffice here?

Can somebody please explain slowly and in complete layman's terms how this is working? I'm really a novice programmer at best and this stuff is confusing the hell out of me, so please bear with me, I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed, as the Smashmouth song goes. All joking aside, I'd appreciate if you could break down what is going on.

```
//count the occurrences of each letter
public static int[] countLetters(char[] chars){
//declare and create an array of 26 int 
int[] counts = new int[26];

//for each lowercase letter in the array, count it
 for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < chars.length; currentIndex++)
counts[chars[currentIndex] - 'a']++;

return counts;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alrightey so this line:

```
counts[chars[currentIndex] - 'a']++;
```

Is short for all of this:

```
// Get the current character from the array:
char character = chars[currentIndex];

// Characters are just numbers. Check out e.g. an "ASCII table".
// So, let's start treating them like numbers and take 'a' from that.
int indexInCounts = character - 'a';

// Increase the count for that letter:
counts[indexInCounts] = counts[indexInCounts] + 1;
```

## Why 'a'?

Arrays start at 0 - you mentioned that in your question so it looks like you've got the hang of those so far. So, if we want counts[0] to represent the number of a's in the input, then we'll need to put 'a' at 0.

- 'a'-'a' is 0.
- 'b'-'a' is 1.

etc.

So, conveniently, taking away 'a' from our input character gives us a number that'll work great for our array index.

## Letters taking away letters is so weird!

Computers only really deal with numbers. Pull up [an ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), and you get an easy way to see how letters map to the underlying numbers (in the ASCII encoding scheme):

- 97: Lowercase 'a'
- 98: Lowercase 'b'
- 99: Lowercase 'c'
  .. And so on!

Hopefully you can see where that's going!

98 (*b*) - 97 (*a*) gives us that index of 1, for example.

## Try it out, but don't forget those brackets!

If you want to experiment, you could swap out that line for the ones above, but don't forget the brackets of your for loop!

```
for(int a=...)
    doSomething(); // Only this first line is looped
    doSomethingElse(); // This happens *once*!
```

This is called *implicit brackets* and is also just a convenience thing. So, here's the full, expanded version:

```
for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < chars.length; currentIndex++)
{
    // Everything in those brackets will be repeated.

    // Get the current character from the array:
    char character = chars[currentIndex];

    // Characters are just numbers. Check out e.g. an "ASCII table".
    // So, let's start treating them like numbers and take 'a' from that.
    int indexInCounts = character - 'a';

    // Increase the count for that letter:
    counts[indexInCounts] = counts[indexInCounts] + 1;

}
```

## Am I supposed to write stuff like that straight away?

**Not really, no!** In reality, you'd typically start out with the expanded version seen above (although most would immediately use `counts[indexInCounts]++;`). When a variable is only used *once* it's often easier to then substitute the actual value in - like this, without all those comments:

```
char character = chars[currentIndex];

int indexInCounts = character - 'a'; // Character is only used once.

counts[indexInCounts]++; // indexInCounts is only used once.
```

Step 2:

```
char character = chars[currentIndex];
counts[character - 'a']++; // Character is only used once.
```

Finally, the magical line is back:

```
counts[chars[currentIndex] - 'a']++;
```

## Predicting errors

If you think you've got the hang of it then try and predict what error you'll get if you chuck an evil space character into the input.

Here's a spoiler:

> You'll get an **index out of range** exception. Space is *32* on that ASCII table. `32 - 97` is very much a negative number, and very much out of range of the acceptable 0-25 of your `counts` array!

P.s. `I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed` - I will forever and always disagree (*except about the song; that's great*) :) Everybody has to start somewhere and you're giving it a try so I wish you all the best!

Comment: To add to that ending: _You'll never shine if you don't glow_!

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. It was a bit strange to see an array reference another array index value. Though, as I understand it, counts computes the index it will add 1 to by taking the character from the currentIndex value of the chars array, then it subtracts the numeric value of 'a' which is 97. It all results in a comfortably precise array set for count, barring characters that fall out of the lowercase letter range. Thanks for the know how, I feel kind of silly now, ha.

Comment: @Strom no problem at all! Hopefully you saw all of it by the way (I edited the answer a few times - either refresh or check for the small "answer edited - click to refresh" button at the top of it).

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate the time you took to lay it all out! Coding has always been much easier for me to grasp when it's compared to real life concepts. A previous issue I had was understanding  a for statement within a for statement, both had 9 iterations. Somebody described it as the big cog(the first for) turning once which made the second cog(the second for) turn 9 times. Descriptions like that I personally find the most helpful in helping to understand a concept, along with breaking down the code into smaller steps, which you managed to do, so it's vastly appreciated and helpful!

Comment: @Strom Ah that's an interesting analogy - I've never heard a for loop described as a cog before - I recently suggested e.g. copy/pasting the code that many times to "unravel" a loop to make it more real that way - I'm glad it helped! :)